# Can't connect to web service by JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I use jquery (ajax) to connect to a web service which returns string , it is not working with me. it always go to error function. here is my web service :

```
 [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("GetImage")]
        public string GetImage(string base64String, string imgName,string reqTitle , string reqSubject, string reqStatus,string Creator , DateTime creationdate )
        {

            try
            {
                using (PhMobAppEntities context = new PhMobAppEntities())
                {
                    ClaimsApproval _ca = new ClaimsApproval();
                    _ca.imageBasestrg = base64String;
                    _ca.imageName = imgName;
                    _ca.Creator = Creator;
                    _ca.CreationTime = creationdate;
                    _ca.ReqStatus = reqStatus;
                    _ca.ReqTitle = reqTitle;
                    _ca.ReqSubject = reqSubject;
                    context.ClaimsApprovals.Add(_ca);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return "Success";
                }

            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {

                var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                        .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

                var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

                var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

                throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
            }
        }
```

and here is my js code :

```
  $("#sendphoto").click(function () {
        var url = "http://41.128.183.109:1212/api/Data/GetImage";
        var data = {
           imgName: "test"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'Get',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
alert("Success");


            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Please Check Your Internet Connection");
            }
        });

    });
```

It is running ok when i tested my web service in advanced rest client ,please advice .

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is your Ajax error handler called? Do you get any errors in the browser's dev console? Have you confirmed whether your server-side code is being called?

Comment: it always goto error function                 alert("Please Check Your Internet Connection");

Comment: OK, so jQuery should be passing some details about the error as arguments to your error handier. Update that function to log the details (check the jQuery doco for more info).

Comment: alert `data` in error function to see details.

Comment: @MairajAhmad when i alert data i get [object object]

Comment: When I hit that url in the browser I get: `{"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://41.128.183.109:1212/api/Data/GetImage'."}`

Comment: @rene yes because it take parameters in its function

Answer (score 0):

I tried connecting to your web service and I get the following response:

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://41.128.183.109:1212/api/Data/GetImage'."}
```

I think what you have is an internal problem with your c# code, probably with your routing. Your javascript call is probably working fine, but you are passing only one parameter, "test" while you have many more in your declaration.

What http response code are you getting?

Comment: When i test my web service on advanced rest client it working fine. and return success . my response is [object object]

Comment: Can you put here a sample of your call?